# Best practice of converting JSON message

Tags: json, go, null, iteration

Say I have a JSON message like this:

```
{
    "aaaa": 14,
    "bbbb": "",
    "cccc": {
        "c1": 121,
        "needed": [
            {
                "_c21": 22.25972,
                "_c22": {
                    "needed1": "123",
                    "needed2": "test"
                }
            },
            {
                "_c21": 22.25972,
                "_c22": {
                    "needed1": "123",
                    "needed2": "test"
                }
            },
            {
                "_c21": 22.25972,
                "_c22": {
                    "needed1": "123",
                    "needed2": "test"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I convert it to something like:

```
{
    "needed": [{
            "needed1": "123",
            "needed2": "test"
        }, {
            "needed1": "123",
            "needed2": "test"
        }, {
            "needed1": "123",
            "needed2": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case I think an iteration is needed to retrieve components of `needed1` and `needed2` only. I'm also wondering what the best practice is for Golang of handling nil and empty? (Like in Java, before processing data, it's recommended to use `if` condition to check each key first)

Comment: Decode to Go types matching the structure of the source document, copy Go type matching the structure of the second document, encode to JSON.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter? Be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should give you what you need:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var input = `{
    "aaaa": 142,
    "bbbb": "",
    "cccc": {
        "c1": 121,
        "needed": [
            {
                "_c21": 22.25972,
                "_c22": {
                    "needed1": "123",
                    "needed2": "test"
                }
            },
            {
                "_c21": 22.25972,
                "_c22": {
                    "needed1": "123",
                    "needed2": "test"
                }
            },
            {
                "_c21": 22.25972,
                "_c22": {
                    "needed1": "123",
                    "needed2": "test"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}`

type Json struct {
    Cccc struct {
        NeededList []struct {
            C22 needed `json:"_c22"`
        } `json:"needed"`
    }`json:"cccc"`
}

type needed struct {
    Needed1 string `json:"needed1"`
    Needed2 string `json:"needed2"`
}

func main() {
    j := &Json{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), j)
    result := make([]needed, 0)
    for _, n := range j.Cccc.NeededList {
        result = append(result, n.C22)
    }
    out, _ := json.Marshal(result)
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```